# gp2 to gp3 migration of EBS volume of a Windows EC2 instance

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am planning to migrate the EBS volume of a Windows EC2 instance from gp2 to gp3. Normally for volumes in linux instances, we can go to the Volume console and modify the volume to gp3 configuration directly and no other action is required if there is no increase in size of the volume.
Are the necessary steps the same for an EBS volume of a Windows EC2 instance?

I have not tried this process before on a Windows instance.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. You can simply change the EBS Volume Type.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is indeed very helpful.